# How to make window.clearInterval() work with this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to implement a pomodoro clock, before diving into real code, I was playing with `window.setInterval()` and its counterpart `window.clearInterval`. The problem I am faced with is that I am unable to make `window.clearInterval()` work for me. Have a look at my code please and guide me how to make it work. Thank you

```js
var startTime = 11;
var intervalID;

function downCounter() {
  startTime--;
  $('h2').text(startTime);
}

if (startTime > 0)
  intervalID = setInterval(downCounter, 1000);
else
  clearInterval(intervalID);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` here:

```
if (startTime > 0)
  intervalID = setInterval(downCounter, 1000);
else
  clearInterval(intervalID);
```

will never run.

This block only runs once, before the timer is started, when you *know* that `startTime` is `> 0`.

Check `startTime` in the handler, and clear the interval *there* when it's gone too far:

```js
var startTime = 11;
var intervalID;

function downCounter() {
  startTime--;
  $('h2').text(startTime);
  
  if (startTime <= 0)
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

intervalID = setInterval(downCounter, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `if (startTime > 0)` is checked only the first time. Try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var startTime = 11;
    var intervalID;
    function downCounter() {
        startTime--;
        $('h2').text(startTime);
        if (startTime <= 0){
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    }
    intervalID = setInterval(downCounter, 1000);    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The clearInterval should be called in downCounter function:

```
    function downCounter() {
      startTime--;
      $('h2').text(startTime);
      if (startTime <= 0 ) {
        clearInterval(intervalID);
      }    
    }
```